# how to add edit/delete buttons in each row of datatable

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, datatable

I create a datatable, now I need to edit and delete the records in the table so I want to add delete and edit button next to year column. that column name should be as action.

Action column should be next to the year column and that should contain delete edit buttons.
[image]

index.html

```
 <!doctype html>
            <html class="no-js" lang="zxx">
            
            <head>                
                <title>index</title>                
            
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome-free-5.14.0-web\css\all.css">
            
            </head>
            <body>
        <div class="adapt_area">
            <div class="container">
        
              <table id="newexample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-light" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Subject</th>
                  <th>Year</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
        
            </div>
        </div>  
    
        </body>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>        
   
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    

   
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#newexample').dataTable({      
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "fetchdata.php",
            "aoColumns": [
                  { mData: 'title' } ,
                  { mData: 'name' },
                  { mData: 'year_name' }
                ],
          });
      });
    </script>
    
    </html>
```

fetchdata.php

```
    <?php
    require 'db_connection.php';  
    
    $query = "SELECT notes.title,subject.name,year.year_name from notes
              INNER JOIN subject ON notes.subject=subject.id
              INNER JOIN year ON subject.year=year.id";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    
    $data=array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      $data[] = $row;
    }
    
    $results = ["sEcho" => 1,
              "iTotalRecords" => count($data),
              "iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($data),
              "aaData" => $data ];
    
    echo json_encode($results);    
     ?>
```

Comment: You can use DataTable createdRow attribute to add edit /delete buttons in an empty action column (include the empty column in columnDef). This way you can add row UID in buttons, which will make it easier to trigger click actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well for update and delete button , you need an ID, i assumed the id on database will named as `id`

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#newexample').dataTable({      
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "fetchdata.php",
        "aoColumns": [
              { mData: 'title' } ,
              { mData: 'name' },
              { mData: 'year_name' },
              { 
                 mData: '',
                 render: (data,type,row) => {
                   return `<a href='link_to_edit/${row.id}'>update</a>`;
                 }
              }
            ],
      });
  });
```

reference [this](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this example in the documentation :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#newexample').dataTable( {
        "ajax": "fetchdata.php",
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": -1,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<button id="edit">edit</button>"
        } ]
    } );
 
    $('#newexample tbody').on( 'click', '#edit', function () {
        //the job
    } );
} );
```

so to retrieve data you can use this :

```
var data = table.row(this).data();
```

and data is an array to access data use :

```
data[0],data[1] ....
```

Comment: its work. but how can i get the id of each recoreds? beacuse its need for delete and edit the record.

Comment: yes i make it as a solution. buttons appear on each rows. but i dont know how to get the id of each record.

Comment: the id of what ??

Comment: id of each record. to identify the row to edit or delete.

Comment: you can pass the id like a hidden row from php and after that in the js you can get the id (hidden row) by table.row(this).data(); when clicked on the button.